# Why doesn't C# code build when debugging in vs code (.NET Core)?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C# and visual studio code. I downloaded the .NET Core SDK quite recently, and whenever I try to debug any code it doesn't build.

This is the error message I get in the terminal while debugging:

```
execvp(3) failed.: No such file or directory
The terminal process "dotnet 'build', '/property:GenerateFullPaths=true', '/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

Mac OS - 10.14.6
VS Code ver. - 1.57.0
.NET Core SDK ver. - 3.1.301 (framework)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the "type" of the build task within `.vscode/tasks.json` from *process* to *shell*.

It did work for me. This issue is being tracked at [OmniSharp #4556](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4556)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Removing the following line from the `settings.json` file worked for me:

```
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
```

How to edit the `settings.json` file... https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings